# How to use multi-threading within a loop that iterates through a point cloud in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, thread-safety, boost-thread

I have made a function that estimates the normal vectors of a 3D Point Cloud and it takes a lot of time to run on a cloud of size 2 million. I want to multi-thread by calling the same function on two different points at the same time but it didn't work (it was creating hundreds of threads). Here is what I tried:

```
// kd-tree used for finding neighbours
pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZRGB> kdt;

// cloud iterators
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::iterator cloud_it = pt_cl->points.begin();
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::iterator cloud_it1;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::iterator cloud_it2;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::iterator cloud_it3;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::iterator cloud_it4;

// initializing tree
kdt.setInputCloud(pt_cl);

// loop exit condition
bool it_completed = false;

while (!it_completed)
{
    // initializing cloud iterators
    cloud_it1 = cloud_it;
    cloud_it2 = cloud_it++;
    cloud_it3 = cloud_it++;

    if (cloud_it3 != pt_cl->points.end())
    {
        // attaching threads
        boost::thread thread_1 = boost::thread(geom::vectors::find_normal, pt_cl, cloud_it1, kdt, radius, max_neighbs);
        boost::thread thread_2 = boost::thread(geom::vectors::find_normal, pt_cl, cloud_it2, kdt, radius, max_neighbs);
        boost::thread thread_3 = boost::thread(geom::vectors::find_normal, pt_cl, cloud_it3, kdt, radius, max_neighbs);

        // joining threads
        thread_1.join();
        thread_2.join();
        thread_3.join();

        cloud_it++;
    }

    else
    {
        it_completed = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to call the same function on 3 different points at the same time. Any suggestions for how to make this work? Sorry for the poor code, I'm tired and thank you in advance.

EDIT: here is the find_normal function
Here are the parameters:

```
@param pt_cl is a pointer to the point cloud to be treated (pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::Ptr)
@param cloud_it is an iterator of this cloud (pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::iterator)
@param kdt is the kd_tree used to find the closest neighbours of a point
@param radius defines the range in which to search for the neighbours of a point
@param max_neighbs is the maximum number of neighbours to be returned by the radius search

// auxilliary vectors for the k-tree nearest search
    std::vector<int> pointIdxRadiusSearch; // neighbours ids
    std::vector<float> pointRadiusSquaredDistance; // distances from the source to the neighbours

    // the vectors of which the cross product calculates the normal
    geom::vectors::vector3 *vect1;
    geom::vectors::vector3 *vect2;
    geom::vectors::vector3 *cross_prod;
    geom::vectors::vector3 *abs_cross_prod;
    geom::vectors::vector3 *normal;
    geom::vectors::vector3 *normalized_normal;

    // vectors to average
    std::vector<geom::vectors::vector3> vct_toavg;

    // if there are neighbours left
    if (kdt.radiusSearch(*cloud_it, radius, pointIdxRadiusSearch, pointRadiusSquaredDistance, max_neighbs) > 0)
    {

        for (int pt_index = 0; pt_index < (pointIdxRadiusSearch.size() - 1); pt_index++)
        {
            // defining the first vector
            vect1 = geom::vectors::create_vect2p((*cloud_it), pt_cl->points[pointIdxRadiusSearch[pt_index + 1]]);

            // defining the second vector; making sure there is no 'out of bounds' error
            if (pt_index == pointIdxRadiusSearch.size() - 2)
                vect2 = geom::vectors::create_vect2p((*cloud_it), pt_cl->points[pointIdxRadiusSearch[1]]);


            else
                vect2 = geom::vectors::create_vect2p((*cloud_it), pt_cl->points[pointIdxRadiusSearch[pt_index + 2]]);

            // adding the cross product of the two previous vectors to our list
            cross_prod = geom::vectors::cross_product(*vect1, *vect2);
            abs_cross_prod = geom::aux::abs_vector(*cross_prod);
            vct_toavg.push_back(*abs_cross_prod);

            // freeing memory
            delete vect1;
            delete vect2;
            delete cross_prod;
            delete abs_cross_prod;
        }

        // calculating the normal
        normal = geom::vectors::vect_avg(vct_toavg);

        // calculating the normalized normal
        normalized_normal = geom::vectors::normalize_normal(*normal);

        // coloring the point
        geom::aux::norm_toPtRGB(&(*cloud_it), *normalized_normal);

        // freeing memory
        delete normal;
        delete normalized_normal;

        // clearing vectors
        vct_toavg.clear();
        pointIdxRadiusSearch.clear();
        pointRadiusSquaredDistance.clear();

        // shrinking vectors
        vct_toavg.shrink_to_fit();
        pointIdxRadiusSearch.shrink_to_fit();
        pointRadiusSquaredDistance.shrink_to_fit();
    }
```

Comment: I feel that using threads explicitly like you have done with Boost is overkill for this task; take a look at OpenMP and similar libraries (Cilk, TBB).

Comment: Also, it looks like you need to better define the desired result; at the moment it's not exactly clear if you want to process all the points independently and in parallel or if there is a certain pattern when applying the function to points ("calling the same function on two points").

Comment: it is, it definitely doesn't work. I have heard of TBB but not sure if it works with my point cloud. I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Better try OpenMP first, it's a lot easier to use.

Comment: Sorry, the points are treated independently. Treating one point is not dependent upon treating the previous points in the cloud.

Comment: Why are you creating exactly three (3) threads inside the loop when the points are independent?

Comment: I was trying to test it with three, I am new to multi-threading. My goal is to have as many point treatments at one time as possible. My processor has 4 cores (2 threads each) and the virtual box my program is running on has been allocated 4 out of 8 threads. My project manager says that creating 4 threads should be fine if you have 4 available threads.

Comment: Ok, make sense; however, when using a parallel library like OpenMP or TBB, the library scheduler takes care of distributing the threads between cores or CPU's, based on the hints you give it. Also, I can't see where you're storing the results of the calculation, is there another array to store the normals?

Comment: My program does not store the normal vectors, it only calculates them, normalizes them and then calculates the red, green and blue components of the concerned point as functions of the x, y and z coordinates of the normalized normal (i.e. curr_point.r = normalized_norm.x * 255 and so on). The program gives the desired output but it is really, really slow (around 20 minutes for my 2 million points cloud).

Comment: Anyway, there must be an output array for whatever day is being calculated, else it's a waste of CPU time. Where are the results being stored?

Comment: There was another way to color the graph (using the spherical coordinate system, calculating the inclination and azimuth of the arrow point of the normal and storing that) but the problem was randomly generated colors instead of colors defined by functions (I hope that makes sense).

Comment: This information seems to be less relevant, what matters is where the output destination array is (not obvious form this code, and required for me to write  code sample using OpenMP).

Comment: The results are not stored, I only color the graph (I work on the graph itself using pointers and _not_ a copy as that would take even longer). The result is written to a file. Here is an example of [output](https://scontent-amt2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-0/p206x206/13090387_1063053323733533_49295617_n.png?oh=fac03e7e7c81b37d59c695e13a1e927b&oe=5720018C)

Comment: Please, try to hear me. *In the code you posted, where are the result stored, used, processed etc.?* I .e. I only see you calling the function `geom::vectors::find_normal()`, but I don't know what its parameters are.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand then. If you mean the array of points it is pt_cl->points(). It was what I'm iterating through

Comment: Again, a miss. Do you understand that you're calculating data *B* based on data *A*, in order to use data *B* in a way, later on? The function you;re calling must have a way to output, store etc the data *B*. I can't understand how this is being done. Hope you understand.

Comment: I have added new information, let me know if you understand better. If it doesn't help, a small general example would still help me get introduced to the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't quite get it how the result data is being stored, I'm going to suggest a solution based on OpenMP that matches the code you've posted.

```
// kd-tree used for finding neighbours
pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZRGB> kdt;

#pragma openmp parallel for schedule(static)
for (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::iterator cloud_it = pt_cl->points.begin();
    cloud_it < pt_cl.end();
    ++cloud_it) {
    geom::vectors::find_normal, pt_cl, cloud_it, kdt, radius, max_neighbs);
}
```

Note that you should be using the `<` comparison, and not the `!=` one, -that's how OpenMP works (it wants random access iterators). I'm using the `static` schedule since every element should take more or less identical time to process. If that's not the case, try using `schedule(dynamic)` instead.

This solution uses OpenMP, and you may investigate e.g. TBB as well, though it has a higher entrance barrier than OpenMP and uses an OOP-style API.

Also, repeating what I've said in the comments already: OpenMP as well as TBB are going to handle thread management and load distribution for you. You only pass them hints (such as `schedule(static)`) on how to do it to so as to better suit your needs.

Other than that, please, do get in the habit of repeating as little code as you can; ideally, no code should be duplicated. E.g. when you declare many variables of the same type, or call a certain function a few times in a row with a similar pattern, etc. I also see excessive commenting in the code, with an unclear reason behind it.

Comment: That looks really good, it's definitely a place to start. As for the result data, it is only stored in a text file at the end. The points in the cloud suffer a transformation directly, meaning that there is no new cloud created to be stored. The process is as follows:

> I read a cloud from a text file;
> I perform some operations on it;
> I write the transformed cloud (which is the same reference but a modified cloud) to a file.

Comment: @VladAdrianMoglan , I get the general idea now it seems; if the result goes back *into exactly the same position*, then my code is gong to work. Watch out for the cases where you take element `i` and put the result into a different position `j` however!

Comment: Exactly, that is the case. Anyways, спасибо for the help